# MapQuest Route is not working for some locations in Europe

Tags: mapquest

I have below code to draw routes on the MapQuest map:

```
this.map = L.mapquest.map('map', {
   center: [48.3552767, -99.9995795],
   layers: L.mapquest.tileLayer('dark'),
   zoom: 2,
   zoomAnimation: false,
 });
   
const directions = L.mapquest.directions();
 
 directions.route({
   // these are not wokring
   // start: [47.372219,8.541973],
   // end: [52.18988,21.63049]

   // these are working
   start: [50.86766, 2.84919],
   end: [47.993594, 0.107319]
 }, (err, response) => {
   this.buildRouteLayers(layers, routeLayer, response, length);
 });
```

I observed that I'm facing issues only with any lat/long pair for the route including *Switzerland* and *Poland* remaining are working fine.

Below is the error on the Browser console:

> Uncaught (in promise) No conditions ahead returned. Traffic data is not available for this route.

Answer (score 1):

The origin, 47.372219,8.541973, is in the river. It's a little too far from a navigable road to start the route.

Comment: Great observation!

Answer (score 0):

I use flutter so I have to use the REST API and I have fixed it by adding the following parameter to my URL "ambiguities=check"